# autoit script help!stop process when is IDLE for 1 min

Tags: autoit

I found this interesting script:

> Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 3) ;3 = exact title match
>   Opt("TrayIconDebug", 1)
>
> $S_running = "check-4-app" ;name the script If WinExists($S_running)
>   Then Exit AutoItWinSetTitle($S_running)
>
> $title = "Untitled - Notepad" $count = 0 While 1
>       $state = WinGetState($title)
>       $count += 1
>
> ```
> If $state = 15 Or $state = 47 Or $state = 0 Then $count = 0
>
> If $count > 10 Then WinClose($title)
>
> ToolTip("count = " & $count, 0, 0, "state = " & $state)
> Sleep(1000) WEnd
> ```

Can someone modify this script to STOP and Close automatically
''My-Xtool.exe'' from processes?not from aplications,but only when is
idle for more then 1 min.,is possible that? I ru

n My-Xtool.exe and i see how bytes values are changing,but sometimes that values are static they don't change value anymore that means my .exe goes IDLE,then i want to stop the process automatically,can anyone help me with that please?
thank you

Comment: Superuser isn't a free script writing service. "I've found this code online, please modify it to my case" still sounds like you expect us to do your job. Please try a bit more and ask specific questions, show at least some research effort trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to change to PROCESSES and not Applications tab

Answer (score 0):

Use similar way as me to quit browsers

```
Local $aList = 0
    Local $aProcesses = StringSplit('iexplore.exe|chrome.exe|firefox.exe|safari.exe|opera.exe|slimjet.exe', '|', $STR_NOCOUNT) ; Multiple processes
    For $i = 0 To UBound($aProcesses) - 1
        $aList = ProcessList($aProcesses[$i])
        If $aList[0][0] > 0 Then ; An array is returned and @error is NEVER set, so lets check the count.
;~         _ArrayDisplay($aList)
            Local $bIsProcessClosed = False ; Declare a variable to hold a boolean.
            For $j = 1 To $aList[0][0]
                $bIsProcessClosed = ProcessClose($aList[$j][1]) ; In AutoIt 0 or 1 can be considered boolean too. It's like a bit in SQL or in C, where 1 and 0 means true or false.
                If Not $bIsProcessClosed Then ConsoleWrite('CLOSE ERROR PID: ' & $aList[$j][1] & @CRLF)
            Next
        EndIf
    Next
```